# Should I use a check constraint or a separate table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field that holds one of three values, "TS", "DS" or "NS". Am I better off using a check constraint or changing the field to an int foreign key that points to those values in a lookup table?

The advantage that I see with the check constraint is that in my data access layer I can use a simple enum to string conversion to populate the field.

If I use the lookup table then I have to fetch the table or table record that matches my enum and then populate the integer foreign key into the table, essentially necessitating an extra trip to the DB.

Comment: Why do you think you have to use an identity to enforce this? You could very easily create a table of allowed values with just that column and then a foreign key in your main table. You could still use an enum if you wanted to.

Comment: Yes, that is what I wrote.

Comment: But you don't have to use an int. You could just use the char(2) values in both tables. I would recommend this because it keeps RI in the database and not in the application.

Comment: OK, I see what you're saying. Kind of the best of both worlds. If you write it up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I would except it isn't really an answer. It is highly subject to opinion. :)

Comment: In practice the most used solution for this issue is to have a lookup-table with, all system "constants" to refer to. In this case you can easily add new values, and you dont have to use a ddl command on the table to achieve this. In your data access layer you can access the values once in a cache and build your business logic on top of this. Consider adding a new Value, you would have to change the constraint AND expand your enumeration.